# RegEx - two words before a string (positive lookahead)

Tags: regex

These are example strings. I would like to extract two words after a string "Name, Surname, signature". I got the second part right with `.*(Name, Surname, signature)` but I am not able to limit the results to two words.

**Examples**:

```
Number of hours: 4,Michael KeysName, Surname, signature
stationary 4Martha JohnsonName, Surname, signature
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

```php
\p{Lu}\p{L}*\s+\p{Lu}\p{L}*(?=Name, Surname, signature)
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/W0WyRx/1)

**Explanation**

```php
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \p{Lu}                    any uppercase letter
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \p{L}*                   any letter (0 or more
                           times (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \p{Lu}                    any uppercase letter
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \p{L}*                   any letter (0 or more
                           times (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Name, Surname,           'Name, Surname, signature'
    signature
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```